# HTML input element with type color not showing more button when clicked in cordova built android app

Tags: android, html, cordova

[image]

I am building an android app using cordova. I have used an input element with type color for picking color.

```
<input type="color" class="lineColirPicker noDisplay" name="lineColirPicker" value="#000000" />
```

When I click on color input (using javascript or manually), above popup color picker appears. when I click on empty space where text "More" is expected to come, the Hue, Saturation, Value options appear.

No display class is applied for display: none property (removing that has no effect with the issue) as I am using .click() method on color input in javascript to pick color and I dont want to show the input field to end user.

Other than dispay:none, no other css property is applied to the color input.

I am not able to inspect the color picker tool as it is in the popup.

I ran it a server (using cordova run browser) and checked in android mobiles chrome, then it is showing the more button so the problem is only when I run it inside the app (using cordova run android)

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hey @AnupSharma,
Sorry for the late reply. I filed a bug on chromium about the issue and they told me that android's theme sets the default background colour but doesn't set the text colour on popups. We cannot change that. The only possible solution right now is to use a different android theme.